# Exclude node from search API results based on values in existing fields

Tags: 8, search

My `content` node includes a `verified` checkbox that's marked by a human reviewer who then also enters a date. The node is verified only when the box is checked and the date is entered. A `content` node may be published before it is verified.

How can I keep an unverified content node from appearing in search API results?

One solution is to add a `search API exclude entity` field to the `content` node and to set the value of the exclude field in a presave hook based on the `verified` checkbox and date. This isn't difficult, but it seems there should be a more straightforward way of accomplishing what's needed.

I've looked at modules, but those I've seen don't seem to fit the need. I imagine I'm just missing something obvious, but what is it?

I don't think it's relevant, but I'll mention that I'm using Solr search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given no alternative answers, I solved this problem by

- installing the `Search API Exclude Entity` module
- adding a field of type `Search API Exclude Entity` named `search_exclude` to the `content` node
- adding the following to my custom `rsc` module

  ```
  function rsc_node_presave(EntityInterface $node) {
    switch ($node->getType()) {
      case 'content':
        $node->field_search_exclude->value = <conditions to exclude node>;
        break;
    }
  }
  ```
- going to `/admin/config/search/search-api/index/default_solr_index/processors`
- checking the `Search API Exclude Entity` box
- selecting the `Search API Exclude Entity` tab at the bottom of the page
- checking the `field_search_exclude (content)` box
- reindexing the content

Seems to be working well. When unverified nodes are saved, the search_exclude field is set and that keeps the nodes out of the search results.